# Show products by high int meta_key valve

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, meta-key

I'm trying to show products by high int val(meta_key) but the code adds the posts side by side with the same int value.

```
$args = array(
'posts_per_page' => $limit, 
'orderby'     => 'meta_value',
'meta_key' => 'wpb_post_views_count',
'order' => 'ASC',
'post_type' => 'products',
'post_status' => 'publish',
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

foreach ($query->posts as $key => $post) {
# code here
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'**

> Note that a 'meta_key=keyname' must also be present in the query. Note also that the sorting will be alphabetical which is fine for strings (i.e. words), but can be unexpected for numbers (e.g. 1, 3, 34, 4, 56, 6, etc, rather than 1, 3, 4, 6, 34, 56 as you might naturally expect). Use 'meta_value_num' instead for numeric values. You may also specify 'meta_type' if you want to cast the meta value as a specific type. Possible values are 'NUMERIC', 'BINARY', 'CHAR', 'DATE', 'DATETIME', 'DECIMAL', 'SIGNED', 'TIME', 'UNSIGNED', same as in '$meta_query'. When using 'meta_type' you can also use meta_value_* accordingly. For example, when using DATETIME as 'meta_type' you can use 'meta_value_datetime' to define order structure.

Try:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => $limit, 
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key' => 'wpb_post_views_count',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'post_type' => 'products',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
);
```

For more information: [Orderby Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters)